# Get and pass text from a TextField which is in a custom TableViewCell subclass

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, textfield

How can I use the text in a textField from a custom Cell?

This is the Receiving Controller:

```
class ShowName: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var showName: UILabel!


    @IBAction func unwindToShowNameData(_ unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let sourceViewController = unwindSegue.source as! enterName
            showName.text = sourceViewController.name
    }


    @IBAction func unwindToShowName(_ unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

}
```

This is the Sending Controller:

```
class enterName: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var name: String?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nameCell", for: indexPath) as! nameCell
        return cell
    }



    @IBAction func clickSave(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let cell = nameCell()
        name = cell.nameText.text
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "passData", sender: self)
    }
}
```

This is the class Cell with TextField:

```
class NameCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what kind of task are you going to do.Explain more.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are going to accomplish. A table view with only one row makes no sense. What is the table view going to display? And why is the class named once `nameCell` and then `NameCell`? Please explain in detail what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: That's just an example project. Looks like I did a mistake when I wrote the question. Of course the name is nameCell. In my real project, I have some more rows with textFields and other stuff in it. Its like adding a new contact where I can enter  to example a name. An other ViewController with a TableView gets the data and displays it.

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha

Comment: @vadian is that enough information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that's the same solution as my suggestion in your previous question.

Add a callback in the cell and call it when the text field delegate method is called. Don't forget to connect the text field delegate in Interface Builder.

And please name classes and structs always with starting uppercase letter

```
class NameCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!

    var callback : ((UITableViewCell, String) -> Void)?

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        callback?(self, nameText.text)
    }
}
```

If you have more than one row you need to declare a data source array to maintain the values of the text fields. This is an example for 4 rows

```
var values = ["", "", "", ""]
```

These are the data source methods, in `cellForRow` the callback updates the model

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nameCell", for: indexPath) as! NameCell
    cell.nameText.text = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.callback = { [unowned self] cCell, cName in
        let currentIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cCell)!
        self.values[currentIndexPath.row] = cName
    }
    return cell
}
```

The benefit is you are independent of the cells in the `clickSave` method. Get the values from the data source array. And you can pass the name as `sender` parameter and hand it over in `prepare(for segue`

```
@IBAction func clickSave(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let name = values[0]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "passData", sender: name)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast and detailed answer. Its still not working. Name is still an empty String because Values[0] never adds the text from the textField. Also there is some mistake in your code. Shouldn't it be self.values[currentIndexPath.row] = cName?

Comment: Did you connect the text field delegate? Is `textFieldDidEndEditing` called at all? You're right, `self.` was missing. If you are going to create a form consider to use the Eureka library. It's very powerful.

Comment: Okay I found my problem. The text Field delegate was connected with the View Controller instead to the Table View Cell. Thanks vadian